# Move browser with mouse

Tags: javascript, css, mouseevent, transform, mouselistener

I am looking to try and do something [like this](http://www.havaspeople.com/our-work/) where the content is off the screen and when you move the mouse the browser follows it around.  I was thinking it would be similar to [this](https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/greensock-image-slideshow/) where the edge of the screen animates when the mouse moves.

It looks like in the original example they use JS to change the `transform: matrix`.  On the second link the screen is animated using greensock and the following code to change the CSS:

```
// Mouse move tilt effect
$(document).mousemove(function(event){

    // Detect mouse position
    var xPos = (event.clientX/$(window).width())-0.5;
    var yPos = (event.clientY/$(window).height())-0.5;

    // Tilt the hero container
    TweenLite.to($hero, 0.6, {rotationY:5*xPos, rotationX:5*yPos, ease:Power1.easeOut, transformPerspective:900, transformOrigin:"center"});

    // Update text on the page with the current mouse position
    $(".bottom strong").text(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
});
```

Is it possible to do something similar to do what I need?

Comment: I also came across this example: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/ but that just moves horizontally and not vertically as well.
There is also this example: https://www.html5andbeyond.com/animated-background-css-background-moves-with-cursor/ but that just moves the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how I understood your intentions basically what you need to do is.

1. Create a div container which has width and height greater than window size and fill it up with content
2. Create div container which has width and height equal to window and overflow: hidden and contains the container in 1.
3. Center container in 1 in 2 with `transform: translateX(-25%) translateX(-25%);` and `transition: transform 1s;`

After that

1. Detected mouse position
2. Calculate distance from center of window
3. And based on that add or remove up to 25% to the translateX and translateY value

EDIT:

```
document.querySelector('body').style.transition = 'transform 1s';

window.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
  const absMaxX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  const absMaxY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  const maxDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(absMaxX, 2) + Math.pow(absMaxY, 2));

  const mouseX = event.clientX;
  const mouseY = event.clientY;

  const directionX = mouseX - absMaxX >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
  const directionY = mouseY - absMaxY >= 0 ? 1 : -1;

  const distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - absMaxX, 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - absMaxY, 2))  
  const translation = distance / maxDistance * 100;

  document.querySelector('body').style.transform =
    `translateX(${directionX * translation}px) translateY(${directionY * translation}px)`
});
```

Comment: Thank you your feedback was very helpful.  I know what you are saying but I am just not sure how I would calculate the distance from the center of the screen and then increase the translate.  I thought it would of been something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/antdevine/p9zLxm80/)

Comment: Thank you for that, its a massive help.  Think I need totweek the direction it moves but on a whole that is just what I was after.

Comment: I have created an updated fiddle for it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/antdevine/axqw2821/1/)